# AWS DMS Error - SQL Server to MySQL migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2012, aws-dms

I keep getting this error on AWS DMS, source: SQL Server

```
2017-12-11T17:03:56 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Approve full logging setup for all tables has finished (sqlserver_log_utils.c:1916)

2017-12-11T17:03:57 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Positioning token value upon start is: 'now' (sqlserver_log_utils.c:1999)

2017-12-11T17:03:57 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: mssql_get_highest_lsn(...) obtained '000BEA37:000002D8:0002' as highest LSN via direct setting. (sqlserver_log_queries.c:890)

2017-12-11T17:03:57 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: safeguard_setup(...) TXN name specifier is set to '[QGBKN25OPP34JWHVTELQD5QQD4]' (sqlserver_log_truncation_safeguard.c:868)

2017-12-11T17:03:57 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Starting replication now (replicationtask.c:2313)

2017-12-11T17:03:57 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: SAFEGUARD_POLICY: RELY_ON_SQL_SERVER_REPLICATION_AGENT: A/B latches (sqlserver_endpoint_capture.c:508)

2017-12-11T17:03:57 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: cdcTimeout property is set to 600 (sqlserver_log_processor.c:5596)

2017-12-11T17:05:57 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Throughput monitor: Last DB time scanned: 2017-12-11T17:05:14.173. Last LSN scanned: 000bea37:00000330:0004. #scanned events: 25. (sqlserver_log_utils.c:4542)

**2017-12-11T17:07:34 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Failure in querying for object name associated with partionID '0' [1022504] (sqlserver_log_utils.c:1048)**

**2017-12-11T17:07:34 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: do_organize_fetched_row(...) failed in executing mssql_resolve_object_name(...) [1022504 (sqlserver_log_processor.c:3287)**

**2017-12-11T17:07:34 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: sqlserver_capture_source_loop(...) encountered an unexpeceted error. [1022504] (sqlserver_endpoint_capture.c:808)**

**2017-12-11T17:07:34 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [1022504] (replicationtask.c:2392)**

2017-12-11T17:07:34 [TASK_MANAGER ]W: Task 'QGBKN25OPP34JWHVTELQD5QQD4' encountered a recoverable error (repository.c:4749)

2017-12-11T17:07:34 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Error executing source loop [1022504] (streamcomponent.c:1588)

2017-12-11T17:07:34 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Subtask #0 ended (replicationtask_util.c:937)

2017-12-11T17:07:34 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_RTLLCWE5MKYO2IS7TEJAUMFLGI [1022504] (subtask.c:1350)

2017-12-11T17:07:34 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Stream component 'st_0_RTLLCWE5MKYO2IS7TEJAUMFLGI' terminated [1022504] (subtask.c:1513)

2017-12-11T17:07:34 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task management thread terminated (replicationtask.c:3228)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who runs into this issue in the future..

Try with wildcards first for Database names and table names, etc % and then it should work.

For non SQL people: Note SQL Server database name is already set at the end point, the schema on the End point is usually dbo.